# What is the subject, "there" or "their friend"?

Tags: subjects

> Off they went to find him in the forest, and **there** atop a tall bael tree was **their friend**, sitting tight.

In the second part of the sentence, what is the subject, "there" or "their friend"?

Comment: It is easy to find. This is the reorded sentence: their friend was there atop a tall bael tree. So "their friend" is your answer.

Answer (score 2):

> There atop a tall bael tree was their friend

By simply re-arranging the sentence, you can split it into subject, verb, object:

> ***Their friend*** was **there atop a tall bael tree**

Subject: their friend is the person actually *being atop the tall bael tree*

Comment: Great. I think your post answers the question. +1)